# To set Different Colors For each column in Column Chart Using NPOI excel nuget package in .Net6 Core

Tags: excel, charts, bar-chart, .net-6.0, npoi

I have code to Generate Excel File using Npoi package where my data on excel sheet creates Column Chart. In that I have 4 columns in my column chart where all columns color is blue by default. I want to set custom colors for each Column in Column chart that is I want 4 different colors for 4 columns.
How to achieve this using NPOI Package?

```
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel.Charts;
using NPOI.SS.Util;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ColumnChart
{
class Program
{
    const int NUM_OF_ROWS = 4;
    const int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 2;
    private static void CreateChart(ISheet sheet, IDrawing drawing, IClientAnchor anchor, string serieTitle, int startDataRow, int endDataRow, int columnIndex)
    {
        XSSFChart chart = (XSSFChart)drawing.CreateChart(anchor);

        IColumnChartData<string, double> columnChartData = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreateColumnChartData<string, double>();
        IChartLegend legend = chart.GetOrCreateLegend();
        legend.Position = LegendPosition.Bottom;

        IChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
        bottomAxis.MajorTickMark = AxisTickMark.None;
        IValueAxis leftAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateValueAxis(AxisPosition.Left);
        leftAxis.Crosses = AxisCrosses.AutoZero;
        leftAxis.SetCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.Between);


        IChartDataSource<string> categoryAxis = DataSources.FromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(startDataRow, endDataRow, 0, 0));
        IChartDataSource<double> valueAxis = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(startDataRow, endDataRow, columnIndex, columnIndex));
        var serie = columnChartData.AddSeries(categoryAxis, valueAxis);
        serie.SetTitle("Categories of Risk Associated");

        chart.Plot(columnChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook())
        {
            ISheet sheet = wb.CreateSheet();

            IRow row;
            ICell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++)
            {
                row = sheet.CreateRow((short)rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++)
                {
                    cell = row.CreateCell((short)colIndex);
                    if (colIndex == 0)
                        cell.SetCellValue("X" + rowIndex);
                    else
                    {
                        var x = colIndex * (rowIndex + 1);
                        cell.SetCellValue(x * x + 2 * x + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 10, 12);

            CreateChart(sheet, drawing, anchor, "s1", 0, 3, 1);
            using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\columnChart.xlsx"))
            {
                wb.Write(fs, false);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample of ColumnChart Generated**
[image: Sample of ColumnChart Generated]

**Sample of ColumnChart Wanted**
[image: Sample of ColumnChart Wanted]

Comment: Did you share the correct code? Generated chart has 6 columns, but in the code, you specified 2 columns. How many series did you create?

Comment: Yes,Code is correct,I have edited chart now as per code given. I want to know How to set Colors to each column in chart using NPOI package.  @user2250152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following code after `chart.Plot(columnChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);`

```
chart.Plot(columnChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

var plotaArea = chart.GetCTChart().plotArea;
plotaArea.barChart[0].ser[0].dPt = new List<NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_DPt>();

for(int index = 0; index < endDataRow - startDataRow; index++)
{
    var dpt = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_DPt();
    dpt.idx = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_UnsignedInt();
    dpt.idx.val = (uint)index;
    dpt.spPr = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_ShapeProperties();
    var solidFill = dpt.spPr.AddNewSolidFill();
    var color = solidFill.AddNewSrgbClr();
    // random color
    color.val = new byte[] { (byte)(125 + index*5), (byte)(50 + index * 8), (byte)(100 + index * 11) };

    plotaArea.barChart[0].ser[0].dPt.Add(dpt);
}
```

With random color the result is

[image]

You will need to add your logic to `for` loop and set the `color.val` based on the current `dataRow`.

`System.Drawing.Color` can help you. You can set the value like this:

```
color.val = new byte[] { Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G, Color.Red.B }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code after `chart.Plot(columnChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);`

```
 chart.Plot(columnChartData, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

 var plotaArea = chart.GetCTChart().plotArea;
 plotaArea.barChart[0].ser[0].dPt = new 
 List<NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_DPt>();

 for (int index = 0; index < endDataRow - startDataRow; index++)
 {
  var dpt = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_DPt();
  dpt.idx = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_UnsignedInt();
  dpt.idx.val = (uint)index;
  dpt.spPr = new NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Dml.Chart.CT_ShapeProperties();
  var solidFill = dpt.spPr.AddNewSolidFill();
  var color = solidFill.AddNewSrgbClr();

  // Define colors based on index
  switch (index % 4)
  {
    case 0: // Orange
        color.val = new byte[] { Color.Orange.R, Color.Orange.G, Color.Orange.B };
        break;
    case 1: // Green
        color.val = new byte[] { Color.Green.R, Color.Green.G, Color.Green.B };
        break;
    case 2: // Red
        color.val = new byte[] { Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G, Color.Red.B };
        break;
    case 3: // Black
        color.val = new byte[] { Color.Black.R, Color.Black.G, Color.Black.B };
        break;
  }

   plotaArea.barChart[0].ser[0].dPt.Add(dpt);
 }
```